# Como filtrar escolhas de um campo baseando-se em escolhas de outro campo do formulário no django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, django-admin

No Django Admin tenho uma model quem tem dois campos: `Unidade` e `Localizacao`. Onde `Unidade` tem um `ManyToManyField` para `Localizacao`, como segue abaixo

```py
class Unidade(models.):
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=200)
    localizacao = models.ManyToManyField(Localizacao)
    ordem = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Ordem', unique=True, blank=False)

class Localizacao(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=200)
    .
    .
```

E no cadastro abaixo eu tenho que selecionar uma Unidade e queria que apenas as localizações daquela unidade aparecessem como opção pra mim, no entanto aparecem todas as localizações.
Tentei fazer algo usando javascript, mas dessa forma eu peguei apenas o nome da Unidade e não a localização que tem nela.
Alguém me indicaria uma maneira de fazer isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor solução que encontrei até o momento foi usar a biblioteca [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) a seção que foi [essa](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form).

Answer (score 0):

Leonardo, vou responder seguindo a sua pergunta "Como filtrar escolhas de um campo baseando-se em escolhas de outro campo do formulário no django?" utilizando JavaScript pq não entendi a sua descrição do seu problema.

A princípio considero que as unidades (filiais, Estados, setor...) já estejam cadastrados e que os itens que fazem referência a eles (funcionários, cidades, produtos...) já estão devidamente cadastrados também.

Ou seja, ao escolher um Estado, vc listará todas as cidades daquele estado. escolhe uma filial, apresenta todos os funcionários. Escolhe um setor e aparecem todos os produtos referentes.

**1º passo**

- crie uma pasta de 'templates' no diretório do app.
- crie um arquivo html de nome que vc queira "*cad_alunos.html*"

**2º passo**

- copie o código html que está no arquivo change_form localizado em: /home/???/.virtualenvs/SEU_PROJETO/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html
- cola o código no teu "*cad_alunos.html*"

**3º passo**

- localize no **cad_aluno.html** **<form {% if has_file_field %}enctype=** e acrescente: *data-local-url="{% url 'ajax_escolha_local' %}* desta maneira:

```
<form {% if has_file_field %}enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %}action="{{ form_url }}" method="post"
    id="{{ opts.model_name }}_form" data-local-url="{% url 'ajax_escolha_local' %} novalidate>
```

- localize **{% block field_sets %}** e cole antes de terminar o bloco `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`
- cole logo depois o script

```
    <script>
       $("#id_localizacao").change(function () {
          var url = $("#{{ opts.model_name }}_form").attr("data-local-url");
          var localizacaoId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
              url: url,
              data: {
                'id_localizacao': localizacaoId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                  $("#id_unidade").html(data);
                }
              });

            });
    </script>
```

**4º passo**

- crie um arquivo *forms.py* e uma class pro formulário (não se esqueça de fazer as importações de acordo com o teu projeto)

```
from django import forms
from outroapp.models import Localizacao, Unidade
from .models import CadastroAluno


class CadastroAlunoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    unidade = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Unidade.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = CadastroAluno
        fields = ('mensagem', 'texto1', 'texto2', 'unidade', 'localizacao')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['localizacao'].queryset = Cidades.objects.none()

        if 'unidade' in self.data:
            try:
                unidade_id = int(self.data.get('unidade'))
                self.fields['localizacao'].queryset = Localizacao.objects.filter(id_unidade=unidade_id)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass 
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['localizacao'].queryset = self.instance.localizacao
```

Neste caso, o modelo *CadastroAluno* em questão não tem a Unidade, só a localização, então posso no forms usar para listar, mas na hora de cadastrar, não ser usada. Caso precise cadastrar, é só tirar a referência antes do *class Meta* e acrescentar o item lá no models.py

**5º passo**

- na pasta templates crie um arquivo html qualquer "escolha_de_localizacao.html"
- cole esse código que vai listar o DropDown exatamente no item localizacao

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for local in localizacao %}
<option value="{{ local.pk }}">{{ local.nome }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

é só esse trecho mesmo... sem cabeçalho sem rodapé, sem load, só isso

**6º passo**

- em **views.py** vc vai fazer a referência ao html que irá atualizar o DropDown quando fizer a escolha de Unidade

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from outroapp.models import Localizacao

def nome_que_eu_quiser(request):
    unidade_id = request.GET.get('unidade')
    localizacao = Localizacao.objects.filter(id_unidade=unidade_id)
    return render(request, 'escolha_de_localizacao.html', {'localizacao': localizacao})
```

**7º passo**

- imaginando que não tenha um arquivo **urls.py** no app, pode inserir no **urls.py** lá do diretório do projeto mesmo o seguinte caminho:

```
[...outros imports]
from django.urls import path
from app_que_está_o_cadastro_de_alunos import views

 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 [...]
 path('ajax/escolha-unidades/', views.nome_que_eu_quiser, name='ajax_escolha_local'),
```

**8º passo**

- no **admin.py** é só fazer o registro

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CadastroAluno, 
from .forms import CadastroAlunoForm


@admin.register(CadastroAluno)
class CadastroAlunoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CadastroAlunoForm
    list_filter = ('mensagem', 'texto1')
    add_form_template = 'cad_alunos.html'
    change_form_template = 'cad_alunos.html'
```

Uma alternativa exclusivamente em Django, eu ainda não consegui fazer.
Espero ter ajudado e não ter esquecido de nada...